# CoreTelephony framework available for Facetime too?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-telephony, facetime

I'm develloping an app that works with facetime. Unfortunatly, there is not yet Facetime frameworks or APIs available, so I'm working with what I have. Like you all must know, when a Facetime call is placed, the native Phone app does the job. The only problem is that when the call is over, it stays in there.

What I want to do is to, once the call ended, send a local notification to the user to ask if he wants to get back to my app, all this with the help of CoreTelephony framework. I know it is a work-in-progress framework and that it's still a private one, BUT:

Can I use that framework in my app and publish it, without been rejected by Apple?

Does that framework works for Facetime too? I can't get it work.
**Here is what I did:**

- I first imported the framework in my appDelegate header file
- And then...

.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
 NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");


CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
 callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call){

  if (call.callState == CTCallStateDialing){ 
   NSLog(@"Call Dialing");
  }
  if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected){ 
   NSLog(@"Call Connected");
  }
  if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected){ 
   NSLog(@"Call Disconnected");
  }
 };
}
```

Nothing gets traced. Any ideas?

**Update:** I just run a little test, I figured out that my code works perfectly with an actual phone call. The CTCallCenter block must be placed in the applicationDidBecomeActive method tho. I also realized that (like the Apple documentation says), the frameworks dispatches those notification only when you're in your app. Suspended mode doesn't get any kind of notification.

Comment: I just run a little test, I figured out that my code works perfectly with an actual phone call. The CTCallCenter block must be placed in the applicationDidBecomeActive method tho.

I also realized that (like the Apple documentation says), the frameworks dispatches those notification only when you're in your app. Suspended mode doesn't get any kind of notification. What a crap...

As somebody made this possible then? I there an effective way to come back to your application, after a facetime call???

thanx! and good night (oh my! it's 2:30 am already)

Answer (score 0):

There's a new CallKit SDK in iOS 10 that allows for detecting of VoIP calls (including FaceTime) even without VoIP entitlements. [Here's a great answer explaining how just to use the observer part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014975/detect-phone-calls-on-ios-with-ctcallcenter-swift)